# Encajar dos divs

Tags: html, css, api, facebook

Buenas, necesito orientación para hacer que una galería de Flickr y una mapa de Google Maps encajen en una página.

Necesito que la mitad izquierda de la página muestre la galería y la mitad derecha el mapa de Google Maps.

El código HTML que estoy usando el siguiente:

```
    <title>Search results</title>
```

```
<fieldset id="googlemaps">
    <legend>
        Google Maps search for the location
        <c:out value="${param.searchQuery}" />
    </legend>


    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
  function initMap() {
    var uluru = {lat: ${lat}, lng: ${lng}};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 13,
      center: uluru
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: uluru,
      map: map
    });
  }
</script>

    <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDMPX-BlAy9WQULw6ghUPdinLeGACrjA70&callback=initMap">
</script>


</fieldset>

<fieldset id="flickr">
    <legend>
        Flickr search for the location
        <c:out value="${param.searchQuery}" />
    </legend>

    <c:forEach items="${requestScope.photos.photo}" var="photo">
        <img
            src='http://farm<c:out value="${photo.farm}"/>.staticflickr.com/<c:out value="${photo.server}"/>/<c:out value="${photo.id}"/>_<c:out value="${photo.secret}"/>.jpg' />
        <br />
        <form action="/facebookPostCreation" method="post">


            <textarea hidden="" name="message">I just liked a Flickr photo via Project TOROID. See it on http://farm<c:out
                    value="${photo.farm}" />.staticflickr.com/<c:out
                    value="${photo.server}" />/<c:out value="${photo.id}" />_<c:out
                    value="${photo.secret}" />.jpg</textarea>
            <br>
            <div class="bottom_links">
                <button type="submit" class="button">Post in Facebook</button>
                <button type="button"
                    onClick="javascript:window.location.href='index.html'"
                    class="button">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </c:forEach>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es fácil, te recomiendo tomar este tutorial de flexbox => [Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

En realidad te recomiendo esta página Web como una fuente muy buena de aprendizaje CSS que te va a sacar de mas de un apuro, pero ahora vamos con tu problema.

Lo primero de todo es crear un div que usaremos como **contenedor principal** que encapsulara todo el código html que has puesto, le puedes poner el nombre de clase que quieras para acceder a el mediante ***CSS***, yo le puse ***"flexbox"*** (que original) y dentro de el crear **dos divs mas** que representaran cada una de las columnas, donde cada uno encapsula tus etiquetas fieldset *(es decir, uno encapsulará tu galería Flicker y el otro tu Mapa)*

Lo he probado en [JSBIN.COM](http://%20.flexbox%20%7B%20display:%20-ms-flex;%20display:%20-webkit-flex;%20display:%20flex;%20%7D%20%20.flexbox%20%3E%20div%20%7B%20width:%2050%25;%20padding:%2010px;%20%7D%20%20.flexbox-container%20%3E%20div:first-child%20%7B%20margin-right:%2020px;%20%7D) y me funciona correctamente en tu código.

```
.flexbox {
display: -ms-flex;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
}

.flexbox > div {
width: 50%;
padding: 10px;
}

.flexbox > div:first-child {
margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Como han respondido mas arriba, un framework como ***Bootstrap, Foundation, Materialize...*** pueden ayudarte a maquetar los elementos de tu página web muy facil con sus sistemas de grillas los cuales son todos muy parecidos (por no decir los mismos)

¡Un saludo!

Answer (score -1):

Puedes utilizar `bootstrap`, así no sólo logras lo que quieres sino que también lo harás responsive y se verá bien en cualquier dispositivo y al div de la galería le das 6 columnas y al div donde está el mapa le das 6 columnas también

```
<div class="row">
<div id="galería" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      ....
</div>
<div id="mapa" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      ....
</div>
</div>
```

En la página de bootstrap hay mucho material introductorio que te será útil. Te dejo el Link: http://www.getbootstrap.com